# Proof for $C \sqsubseteq D \iff \top \sqsubseteq \neg C \sqcup D$, where $C$ and $D$ are concepts or classes

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

In Semantic Web literature, I came across the following.

$C \sqsubseteq D \iff \top \sqsubseteq \neg C \sqcup D$

The above is being mentioned as an axiom equivalence often used
for normalization purposes.

*(If you have access, you can view [the resource](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3642230318), page 100.)*

In the given equivalence relation.

$C$, $D$ are classes. Classes or concepts in Semantic Web provide an abstraction mechanism for
grouping resources with similar characteristics. Classes may be
thought of as a grouping or a set. Things in the same class have
something(s) in common.

$\top$ is the superclass or universal class.

The literature does not mention any proof of the equivalence relation nor
can I find the proof anywhere after an extensive search.

Can you please suggest how the relation can be proven? That must render a better comprehension of it, at least for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, $\lnot C \sqcup D \sqsubseteq \top$, because $\top$ is the *universal* class.

So, assume that $\top$ is not included into $\lnot C \sqcup D$; this means that there is something (call it $x$) that does not belong to $\lnot C \sqcup D$.

By property of *union*, this means that neither $x$ belongs to $\lnot C$, nor $x$ belongs to $D$.

But if $x$ does not belong to  $\lnot C$, by property of *complement* it belongs to $C$ and $C$ is included into $D$: thus $x$ belongs to $D$ and we have a contradiction.

---

The other direction of the proof is similar: assume that there is something that is in $C$ and not in $D$.

Thus $x$ belongs to $C \sqcap \lnot D$ and thus, by De Morgan, $x$ does not belong to $\lnot C \sqcup D$, contradicting the fact that the *universal* class is included into it.